# Asp.NET server control events not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-server-controls

Thanks for all who reads. I have a code issue that has been discussed many times on stackoverflow, but I can't make the provided solutions work.

It's about server control that contain other controls and I can't fire their events.

My issue is simple, i need to add any numbers ok LinButton into my server control. this is my code:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < IndiceValue; i++)
    {
        LinkButton imageTemp = new LinkButton() { CommandName = String.Format("{1}_{0}", CommandNames, i), Text = i.ToString(), ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()};
        imageTemp.Click += ImageTempOnClick;
        this.Controls.Add(imageTemp);
    }
    base.CreateChildControls();
}
```

I have a custom event in my control:

```
public delegate void IndiceFiabiliteCommand(object sender, IndiceFiabiliteCommandEventArg e);
public event IndiceFiabiliteCommand Command;
```

And theorically, when any of the LinkButton is clicked, I want the user to be warn that any of the LinkButton has been clicked. I give him all the needed infos but i don't think this part is the problem.

Last thing to know is that I implement `INamingContainer` and I tried to implement both, `IPostBackDataHandler` and IPostBackEventHandler but it didn't worked.

I hope it's understandable enough

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

You cannot have dynamically created control with dynamic id. Change the code to

`... i.ToString(), ID = i.ToString()`

Basically, dynamic control's ID must be same as the ID originally created.

Otherwise, new control is created on every post-back, and it cannot find the control which causes the post-back.

***FYI:** if you need to catch an event, I would like to suggest to use **[CompositeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)** which already have INamingContainer.*

***Note:** it is just what I found based on your code; it might be other issue too.*

Comment: it works! thanks, I removed the id and INamingContainer did the job.